# AD: 2 users, same password

Tags: active-directory

Not sure how it's done i'll explain the scenario.
normal users have their daily access, but some require have local admin rights from time to time.

The idea, is to have their normal ad account "user1", but also a poweruser account "PWuser1"

so when they need the extra access, they auth with the PWuser1 and password, instead of having to relog, or be signed in with extra access when its not needed

The trick is, they should be using the same password, so when user1 changes password the same password should be set for PWuser1.

Is there any way to do this, to "replicate" the password on the 2 accounts.

Comment: Doesn't UAC already help with the "extra access only when needed" part?

Comment: If they for example need to run an elevated commandprompt, they need the administrator access, so they would need the extra priviliges
so the UAC would not help in this case, since it would need an admin user etc

Comment: Right, so they use the admin user all the time, but UAC keeps all programs at regular privileges, and "elevating" gives admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

**net localgroup Administrators [username] /add /domain** will promote a user to being a local admin, rather than having to do this manually.

As for syncing passwords, there is no legitimate way to discover a user's existing password (although there are hacks, but best avoided) So, that could only be done at a password change.

The problem I forsee with your approach is that the two accounts will have entirely different files and settings. Thus, none too workable. As single local-admin account with UAE would be more workable.

If you feel that is not secure enough, you might add a software policy to stop the user from running unofficial software. You can do this from group policy, or use a bespoke tool: http://sf.net/projects/softwarepolicy

Bear in mind that being a limited user is not a security panacea anyway. The reason most malware is blocked, is because the malware was not *designed* to run under limited rights.

Comment: hi, thanks for response, the idea was also that the "admin account" would be excluded from login etc, since it would only be used, for elevating user rights when needed.
Guess there is no easy way to copy the hashed password automatically to another user account.

Comment: No, although you could programmatically change the password in both using 'net user username password [/domain]' -or write a GUI applet to do this with something like AutoIt.